# How do I get back Solution Explorer when the debugger is running in VS Express 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I don't know what I did, but somehow my solution explorer disappeared in **Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web** whenever the debugger is running. I have to stop running my app any time I need to open a file that is not currently open. How can I get it back?

[image]

Comment: View -> "Solution explorer" or `Ctrl + Alt + L` should do it.

Comment: @FrankThomas that fixed it. I will mark your answer as accepted if you post one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If for some reason Solution explorer is closed, you can reopen it from the view menu, or with the key command `Ctrl + Alt + L`.

Also note visual studio changes window preference sets when going into debug mode (similar to the Eclipse "Perspective" switch, but less jarring), so if you closed it both in normal/design mode and in debug mode, you would likely have to reopen it for both modes separately.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why I was downvoted by the way? I don't normally post in SuperUser. Was this not the correct SE to use?

Comment: I believe your question was on-topic, though you might have gotten a faster result at SO, even though its more off-topic there. Many folks here think anything related to visual studio must be a development question (and thus should be on SO), even when its just a question about how to configure/operate the IDE, not about code in it. Or it may be that that person just downvotes any question with the words 'I don't know what I did but...' or because they believe that you should have been able to figure it out yourself. who knows. Balanced it out for ya. Good luck!